# Trouble with web.xml url pattern

Tags: java, web.xml

In my `web.xml` I have URL pattern for servlet like this:

`<url-pattern>/*/myservice</url-pattern>`

So I want to call it using `blablabla/myservice` also as `anyWord/myservice`.

But it doesn't work. It work only if I call it using this URL: `/*/myservice`  (with asterisk in URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that.
According to the Servlet 2.5 Specification (and things aren't that different in other levels of the specification), chapter SRV.11.2:

- A string beginning with a `/` character and ending with a `/*` suffix
  is used for path mapping.
- A string beginning with a `*.` prefix is used as an extension mapping.
- A string containing only the `/` character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and
  the path info is null.
- All other strings are used for exact matches only.

Your case falls under the 4th bullet, so exact mapping is used.

To circumvent that, use a mapping of `/` (third case). Map all requests to go to a particular servlet, and have that servlet re-route requests to handlers of some sort (either other servlets, or some custom classes).

For example:

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
<servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
```

And then, within `MyServlet`'s code, inspect the URL that you received in the request (using `request.getPathInfo()`) and use the value to forward the request to other handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filter while your url pattern is /* and inside the filter decide which redirection you required.

```
<filter>
<display-name>MyFilter</display-name>
<filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.MyfilterClass</filter-class>
```

```
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about two ULR-mapping  sections?

```
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>ModifyMemberSVL</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/ModifyMember</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>ModifyMemberSVL</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/Administration/Add_Member/ModifyMember</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: That would require the OP to change his `web.xml` every time a new qualifier is added to his URL pattern.